# Drupal 7 - Apache solr search custom fields and order the fields

Tags: drupal-7

I have problems with **Apache Solr Search** In Drupal 7 . I have been setup a site Drupal 7 with module Apache Solr Search Integration. Now I have a content type called **Content_Type_A** and the **Content_Type_A** has 5 fields below:

1.field_1

2.field_2

3.field_3

4.field_4

5.field_5

a. The problems i want to use **Apache Solr Search** to search **the content only searching in 3 fields: field_1, field_2, field_3**.

b.  I want to sort them by pertinence. The pertinence for each field of a content must be priorized with this order, from the most important to the less important :

- field_3
- field_1
- field_2

Here is an example for you to understand it clearly:
- let say we have 3 content :

```
- Content 1 : field_3: "The test title 1", field_1: "What Tont"

- Content 2 : field_3: "Tont center search", field_1: "Apple live"

- Content 3 : field_3: "La balle blanche", field_1: "test search"
```

- If I search for this text : "Tont" results must be displayed in this order :

  - First one is Content 2 "Tont center search", because "Tont" is in its field_3
  - Second one is Content 1 because "Tont" is in the name of the field_1
- If I search for this text : "search" results must be displayed in this order :

  - First one is Content 2 "Tont center search", because "search" is in its field_3
  - Second one is Content 3 because "search" is in the name of the field_1

Any idea for me?

I hope you can help me about this.

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please be clear on the data format which you are going to prepare for indexing. If you are having it as csv, then you can define the field header in the schema, and declare whether that field can be indexed or not using the flag

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```